# OpenPyXL - Entering Values On Specific Row From List Of Rows

Tags: python, sql, openpyxl, pyodbc

I am saving a SQL query results with `pyodbc` and looking to insert the rows in an Excel file with `OpenPyXL`, but starting on a specific row.

I have been able to do this with a double `for` loop, basically deconstructing the results in rows and then cells, then entering them one by one.

If I was ok with pasting the results wherever the cursor is, the simple `append` method would be sufficient, but simply because I want to specify which row to start pasting it, it seems like a lot of extra hussle.
Is there a better way to do this?

```
import pyodbc
import openpyxl

# openpyxl config
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = 'test1.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

# Connect to SQL Server's DB
conn = pyodbc.connect(Driver='{SQL Server}',
                      Server=server_sql,
                      Database=database,
                      Trusted_Connection='yes')
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Query
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table1')
result = cursor.fetchall()

# Copy to Excel
for num, row in enumerate(result, start=1):
    for num2, val in enumerate(row, start=1):
        ws.cell(row=6+num, column=num2).value = val
```

Comment: The openpyxl docs seem to indicate that it can [insert and delete rows and columns](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/editing_worksheets.html#inserting-rows-and-columns) so perhaps you could use an easier way of inserting the data starting at row 1 and then insert blank rows afterward.

Comment: @GordThompson This is not viable, but thanks for pointing the option out